# Is their a way to show first date and last date on this dataset in python

Tags: python, return, dataset, max, min

[image: Screenshot of code]
Hi,
I am trying to find the minimum date and max date found in this dataset, it keeps returning the min and max fields, any idea how to get it to produce the dates? I had it at one point but know is returning this.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is not an index so `index.min()` will give minimum index i.e. 0

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

print(data['Date'].min(), data['Date'].max())
```

If you want to use your commands make the date column as index

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
```